# How to run a .sql file through query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure through which I am creating a dynamic `.sql` file on the server and the file have successfully generated. Now I want o execute the same file through query in the same stored procedure .

I have go through the links and found the below lines useful

```
osql -D db_name -S server_name -U username -P password -i sqlfile
```

**or**

```
sqlcmd -D db_name -S server_name -U username -P password -i sqlfile
```

I have tried to implement the above but it is giving me the error of

> osql is not a recognized option

Please tell me the correct way. Thanks

Comment: `osql` is the old tool - used up to version SQL Server **2000** - `sqlcmd` is the new one that you should be using from SQL Server **2005** onwards

Comment: Giving me the same error for sqlcmd

Comment: To run the above queries, should I have to install any kind of tool??

Comment: If you have SQL Server installed, `sqlcmd` should be on your machine

Comment: Since xp_sqlcmd is switched of in most environments (with good reason btw), I wonder if it wouldn't be easier to simply create the query in a varchar(max) and use `EXEC` on it rather than going through hoops to store the query in a file (= outside of MSSQL) and trying to run it from there !?!  (My first 'huh' actually was: how does 9s)he get the file on disk in the first place as this requires "a higher degree of knowledge on the system" than I would expect from the question. No offence btw!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlcmd` is a command line tool and cannot be called directly from inside a stored procedure.

Use `xp_cmdshell` to execute it:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ‘sqlcmd -D db_name -S server_name -U username -P password -i sqlfile’
```

Comment: Yes, I was exactly doing the same. Does it really require to mention the db_name, server_name etc, because I am already in my SP that is running under a particular Database and Server

Comment: It does, it's an external tool and has no knowledge of your stored procedure's context.